# UITextView setSelectedRange changes editable property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

From the start, my `UITextView` with editable property to true is not editable (via settings in a NIB). The behaviour is such that a user can select and copy text but not edit. This is the way things should be.

However, if I make a call to `setSelectedRange`, a side effect is that the editable property is set to YES.

Setting it back to NO `[textview setEditable:NO]` scrolls to the bottom of the textView and undoes my programmatic selection. It also doesn't work, as editing becomes enabled anyway. The keyboard appears and everything.

I need to be able to select something programmatically and keep the textView in a state where users can only copy and select text.

```
[textView select:self];
[textView setSelectedRange:selectedText];
```

I'm stuck. Looking for any advice you can give.

This doesn't work:

```
[textView select:self];
[textView setSelectedRange:selectedText];
[textView setEditable:NO];
```

I've also tried setting the delegate function `textViewShouldBeginEditing` to return NO:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    return NO;
}
```

That just locks everything down and I can't select any text.

Comment: It's even worse than I thought. setSelectedRange sets editable to YES, isEditing to YES, then calls the various UITextView editing delegates. When a user selects text, none of that happens. I want to mimic a user selecting text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work for me in a similar situation:

- just let the textview be editable
- `[textView setDelegate:self];`
- `[textView select:self];`
- `[textView setSelectedRange:range];`
- add a function `(BOOL)textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` returning `NO`
- and the final trick: assign an empty view as a keyboard for the textview, using:

`textView.inputView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];`

Comment: This is almost what I need. The only problem is that the copy menu becomes much larger with all of the unusable editing commands, which is also a user interface no-no. So the final goal is to hijack the context/selection menu. I'll research that. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: I'm going to add the following to disable the menu: -(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{    
    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    return NO;    
} For convenience, I'll rewrite the answer below and mark this as the answer.

Comment: True, and for my purposes I also found another issue, which is preventing the selection to disappear. I solved it through bluntly resetting the selection to the last valid state on the relevant didChangeSelection callback.

Comment: @mvds textview setdelegate:self does not work, what should I replace self with?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this has already been answered, but here is an improvement I made to keep the popout menu, just disable certain options;

```
-(BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    bool response = [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    if(response && (action == @selector(cut:) || action == @selector(paste:) || action == @selector(delete:) || action == @selector(_promptForReplace:))) {
        return NO;
    }
    return response;
}
```

canPerformAction is called per defined action. Calling the parent method will take care of most of these cases, but I have also decided to disable cut,paste,delete and spelling suggestions (_promptForReplace).

Comment: Ah awesome. I was just about to try an figure out how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: i have used this during all the development process but when submittind, in app review process, Apple says _promptForReplace:  is a non public API. Did someone have a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

The textView should be editable:

```
[textView setEditable:YES];
```

Do the selection:

```
[textView select:self];
[textView setSelectedRange:range];
```

Have these in the delegate:

To disable the menu (not ideal for me but it's ok):

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{    
    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    return NO;    
}
```

To disable the keyboard:

```
textView.inputView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

To disable editing:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView*)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString*)text {
    return NO;
}
```